# Protege 4.2 - OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space on large number of Individuals in an OWL ontology

Tags: java, out-of-memory, owl, ontology, protege4

Im very new to the use of protege and working with ontologies.  Im creating a lil program to chek firewall rules and i have come across the following error while trying to run Pellet resoner, 2 different errors in the log:

### 1

Error 1 Logged at Sun Nov 17 21:49:48 COT 2013
OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.rete.Index$IndexNode.(Index.java:43)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.rete.Index$IndexNode.add(Index.java:55)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.rete.Index$IndexNode.add(Index.java:58)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.rete.Index$IndexNode.add(Index.java:58)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.rete.Index$IndexNode.add(Index.java:58)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.rete.Index$IndexNode.add(Index.java:58)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.rete.Index$IndexNode.add(Index.java:58)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.rete.Index$IndexNode.add(Index.java:58)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.rete.Index$IndexNode.add(Index.java:58)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.rete.Index$IndexNode.add(Index.java:58)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.rete.Index.add(Index.java:173)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.rete.BetaNode.join(BetaNode.java:131)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.rete.Interpreter.processBetaNodes(Interpreter.java:109)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.rete.Interpreter.run(Interpreter.java:236)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.ContinuousRulesStrategy.applyRete(ContinuousRulesStrategy.java:179)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.ContinuousRulesStrategy.complete(ContinuousRulesStrategy.java:291)
    org.mindswap.pellet.ABox.isConsistent(ABox.java:1423)
    org.mindswap.pellet.ABox.isConsistent(ABox.java:1260)
    org.mindswap.pellet.KnowledgeBase.consistency(KnowledgeBase.java:1987)
    org.mindswap.pellet.KnowledgeBase.isConsistent(KnowledgeBase.java:2061)
    org.mindswap.pellet.KnowledgeBase.ensureConsistency(KnowledgeBase.java:2075)
    org.mindswap.pellet.KnowledgeBase.classify(KnowledgeBase.java:2083)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.owlapiv3.PelletReasoner.precomputeInferences(PelletReasoner.java:1067)
    org.protege.editor.owl.model.inference.OWLReasonerManagerImpl$ClassificationRunner.precompute(OWLReasonerManagerImpl.java:417)
    org.protege.editor.owl.model.inference.OWLReasonerManagerImpl$ClassificationRunner.run(OWLReasonerManagerImpl.java:356)

### java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

2

Error 2 Logged at Sun Nov 17 21:50:37 COT 2013
OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    java.util.HashMap.createEntry(HashMap.java:869)
    java.util.HashMap.addEntry(HashMap.java:856)
    java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:484)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.rete.Index$IndexNode.add(Index.java:56)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.rete.Index$IndexNode.add(Index.java:58)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.rete.Index$IndexNode.add(Index.java:58)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.rete.Index$IndexNode.add(Index.java:58)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.rete.Index$IndexNode.add(Index.java:58)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.rete.Index.add(Index.java:173)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.rete.BetaNode.join(BetaNode.java:131)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.rete.Interpreter.processBetaNodes(Interpreter.java:109)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.rete.Interpreter.run(Interpreter.java:236)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.ContinuousRulesStrategy.applyRete(ContinuousRulesStrategy.java:179)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.ContinuousRulesStrategy.complete(ContinuousRulesStrategy.java:291)
    org.mindswap.pellet.ABox.isConsistent(ABox.java:1423)
    org.mindswap.pellet.ABox.isConsistent(ABox.java:1260)
    org.mindswap.pellet.KnowledgeBase.consistency(KnowledgeBase.java:1987)
    org.mindswap.pellet.KnowledgeBase.isConsistent(KnowledgeBase.java:2061)
    com.clarkparsia.pellet.owlapiv3.PelletReasoner.isConsistent(PelletReasoner.java:849)
    org.protege.editor.owl.model.inference.OWLReasonerManagerImpl.getReasonerStatus(OWLReasonerManagerImpl.java:236)
    org.protege.editor.owl.model.OWLWorkspace.updateReasonerStatus(OWLWorkspace.java:750)
    org.protege.editor.owl.model.OWLWorkspace.handleModelManagerEvent(OWLWorkspace.java:351)
    org.protege.editor.owl.model.OWLWorkspace.access$000(OWLWorkspace.java:140)
    org.protege.editor.owl.model.OWLWorkspace$1.handleChange(OWLWorkspace.java:253)
    org.protege.editor.owl.model.OWLModelManagerImpl.fireEvent(OWLModelManagerImpl.java:818)
    org.protege.editor.owl.model.inference.OWLReasonerManagerImpl$ClassificationRunner$1.run(OWLReasonerManagerImpl.java:430)
    java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
    java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

---

i have been reading and I have changed the JVM memory to almost 3GB which is the maximum amount on my laptop. I have double cheked all the data type are acording to design.

In my corrent ontology Im using SWRL rules and i got about 1300 and some individuals and the .owl file is 5.31Mb. Im running a 64bit windows 7.

Im thinking that the main issue is that my laptop cannot run this large ontology. is there any way I could be wrong? I have seen some places where they say that this error msg might be misleading.

how can I fix this issue? what are my options? Im new here but im ready to read a lot =) 
thnx everyone

Comment: Well, seems like your ontology requires more memory than you have available on your machine. Reasoners are greedy programs, often requiring lots of free space. Solutions: Either you assign more memory to the JVM (`xmx`) or you have to use a bigger computer. You can also try to decrease the rules you are using or axioms.

Comment: The memory consumption will depend on the expressivity of the ontology, the number of individuals and the number of rules firing. The ontology you describe is not small, but I'm surprised it does not fit in 3 gigabytes. Can you add details on how exactly you set more memory for Protege?

Comment: In addition to @Ignazio's request for information about how you're setting the memory, can you reproduce this behavior with a smaller ontology of a similar structure?  Can you share your ontology with us?  It will be very hard to diagnose the actual problem (as opposed to just proposing remedies to the symptoms) without some idea of _why_ this is happening.

Comment: hello friends, thank you for your inputs on this issue. I did try with the same ontology but fewer than 100 individuals and still happens. On  @loopasam note, I did read somewhere that this might be a Pellet related error, not directly with protege, how can I be sure? I will like to share the basic ontology with you guys so you can take a look. I dont see where can I attach a file? the actuall content of the individuals are private information, i wont be able to share that.

Comment: You [asked](http://protege-project.136.n4.nabble.com/Protege-4-2-OutOfMemoryError-Java-heap-space-on-large-number-of-Individuals-in-an-OWL-ontology-td4659541.html) the same question on the Protege mailing list and it's where you read about the Pellet error. Protege is just a GUI to interact with your ontology, it doesn't usually cause error problems `out of memory` errors. The error stack refers to `com.clarkparsia.pellet` therefore it seems to be a Pellet related error. Decrease the size of your ontology to 1 individual and increase progressively the number to see if this is the problem.